# Google Apps Script working with selection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, selection

I would like to add a menu item to a Google Sheet that performs a task on the selected cells.  A web search, including Stack Overflow, indicates that the `getActiveRange()` method is the proper approach.   But when I query the returned Range object, regardless of what cells I have selected, it always reports the first row equal to 1 and the number of rows equal to 1.  What should I be using?

Here is a stripped-down script that reproduces the issue:

```
var ss    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

function onOpen() {
  var myMenu = [];
  myMenu.push({name: "Detect selection", functionName: "detectSelection"});
  ss.addMenu("My Menu", myMenu);
}

function detectSelection() {
  var range    = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var firstRow = range.getRow();
  var lastRow  = range.getLastRow();
  var numRows  = range.getNumRows();
  sheet.getRange(1,1).setValue("First Row");
  sheet.getRange(1,2).setValue(firstRow);
  sheet.getRange(2,1).setValue("Last Row");
  sheet.getRange(2,2).setValue(lastRow);
  sheet.getRange(3,1).setValue("Number of Rows");
  sheet.getRange(3,2).setValue(numRows);
}
```

I can select any group of cells I wish, choose "Detect selection" from "My Menu", and the first row, last row, and number of rows will always be reported as 1.

Comment: range.getRow() and range.getColumn() is relative to the upper left corner.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Compare it to what you have and I think you can figure it out for yourself.  The learning experience will be worth it.  You can select any range you want.

```
function runOne() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var rg=sh.getActiveRange();
  sh.clearContents();
  var vA=[['rg.getRow()',rg.getRow()],['rg.getColumn()',rg.getColumn()],['rg.getLastRow()',rg.getLastRow()],['rg.getLastColumn()',rg.getLastColumn()],['rg.getNumRows()',rg.getNumRows()],['rg.getNumColumns()',rg.getNumColumns()]];
  var vB=[];
  for(var i=0;i<rg.getHeight();i++) {
    vB[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<rg.getWidth();j++) {
      vB[i][j]=Utilities.formatString('%s,%s',rg.getRow()+i,rg.getColumn()+j);
    }
  }
  sh.getRange(rg.getRow(),rg.getColumn(),vB.length,vB[0].length).setValues(vB);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow()+1,rg.getColumn(),vA.length,vA[0].length).setValues(vA);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  So when I assign `sheet` as a global variable, certain characteristics, such as the selection, are frozen.  But if I define it dynamically within the function, it can see the current selection.

Comment: I don't think that matters.  Look closer.